# Сортировка строк в файле в соответствии с нумерацией

Tags: python, файлы, сортировка

У меня есть txt-файл с перемешанными внутри строками. Надо просмотреть нумерацию строк (пример: 1: , 2: и т.д.) и отсортировать их в файле

```
filename = input()
file = open(filename, 'r+')
check = dict()
newcontent = """"""
strnum = ''
for i in file.readlines:
    for s in i:
        if i != ':':
            strnum += s
        else:
            check.update([int(strnum), s])
            break
for s in sorted(check).keys:
    newcontent += check[i] + '\n'
file = newcontent
print(file.readlines)
```

Пример ввода:

```
1: Первая строка
10: Десятая строка
5: Пятая строка
8: Восьмая строка
3: Третья строка
```

Пример вывода:

```
1: Первая строка
3: Третья строка
5: Пятая строка
8: Восьмая строка
10: Десятая строка
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я не шарю в питоне вообще, но вы там строку посимвольно перебираете что ли в поисках двоеточия? У вас задача такая именно руками все это сделать ? или почему вы не используете функции для поиска подстроки, либо регулярные выражения? Вам ведь тут надо скопировать и преобразовать в число все что в начале до двоеточия, либо что соответствует `^(\d+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде неудачно использован словарь (хотя можно его заставить работать как вы хотите), перепутаны переменные в последнем цикле, `.keys` не работает, печать печатает не то. Так много всего, что, наверно, проще начать с нуля.

```
# получить имя файла
fname = input()

# прочитать все строки файла в список
with open(fname) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# упорядочить по номеру строки до двоеточия
lines.sort(key=lambda line: int(line[:line.index(':')]))

# распечатать
for line in lines:
    print(line, end='')
```

> ```
> $ cat file.txt
> 1: Первая строка
> 10: Десятая строка
> 5: Пятая строка
> 8: Восьмая строка
> 3: Третья строка
>
> $ echo file.txt | python sort.py
> 1: Первая строка
> 3: Третья строка
> 5: Пятая строка
> 8: Восьмая строка
> 10: Десятая строка
> ```

Но я привык к другому интерфейсу - без использования явного имени файла:

```
import sys

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
lines.sort(key=lambda line: int(line[:line.index(':')]))
for line in lines:
    print(line, end='')
```

> ```
> $ python sort.py < file.txt
> 1: Первая строка
> 3: Третья строка
> 5: Пятая строка
> 8: Восьмая строка
> 10: Десятая строка
> ```

А ещё в операционных системах уже есть подходящая утилита. Код не нужен:

> ```
> $ sort -n file.txt
> 1: Первая строка
> 3: Третья строка
> 5: Пятая строка
> 8: Восьмая строка
> 10: Десятая строка
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
# Открываем файл на чтение
filename = input()
file = open(filename, 'r+')
src_list = []

# Перебираем все строки файла
for line in file:
    split_line = line.split(':') # Разбиваем строку по символу ':'
    num_line = int(split_line[0]) # Преобразуем строку номера в число  
    src_list.append( (num_line, split_line[1])) # Добавляем в итоговый массив
    
src_list.sort() # Сортируем по числовому ключу

print(src_list)
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - "не позорьтесь."
Спасибо за замеченную опечатку!